# Evans PDE, Problem 5, Chapter 2

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle, poissons-equation

I'm taking my first theoretical PDE course in a year and am bashing my head against a rock with this problem.

Prove that there exists a constant $C$, depending only on $n$, such that

$\max_{B(0,1)}|u| ≤ C \max_{∂B(0,1)}|g| + \max_{B(0,1)}| f |)$

whenever $u$ is a smooth solution of

$-\Delta u = f$ in $B(0,1)$

$u = g$ on $∂B(0,1)$

I found similar problems online but their proofs do not make any sense. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried so far? What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: That chapter of Evans' book contains an explicit representation for the solution $u$ in terms of $f$, $g$, and the Green's function for the ball. That is really all that is required.

Comment: @UmbertoP. my teacher did not cover this material yet. He has just introduced the definition of Green's function. That's it.